# The Symfony2 application automatically logs out a user which has more than one role defined

Tags: symfony, roles

I have a Symfony2 application that uses roles to manage authorization. It all works fine when I login with a user that only has one role associated with him, but when I try with one that has more than one role, the application logs him out automatically.

I really don't know what code sample to provide, so any question or suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you define **ROLE HIERARCHY** ? 
so you can have only 1 role, but stacking the permission of role under it.

Something like :

`security.yml` :

```
role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_MANAGER
    ROLE_MANAGER:     ROLE_USER
```

The `ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN` will have all the role under (admin / manager / user).

The documentation for the hierachical role is here : http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#hierarchical-roles

Comment: Because I want more flexibility. I really need the ability to have multiple roles per user. I can explain why, but it's kind of a long explanation and I think it's besides the point.